# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de un atributo para una etiqueta button con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nodejs, ejs

Necesito recibir como parámetro en jQuery un atributo `table` dado a una etiqueta `<button>` como se muestra en la siguiente línea de código:

```
<button type="button" class="btn  ml-2 addCrow" name="bt-addCrow" id="addCrow" table="<%=app%>">Agregar
        </button>
```

La vista de mi página está recibiendo del modelo una variable llamada `<%=app%>`. Mi idea es recibir el nombre de esta variable, que añadirá una nueva fila en el datatable con al recibir el clic del `<button>` "agregar".

Aquí estoy implementando el código del datatable que a partir de ese script:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    let viewConfigurationApp_ = new configurationC();
    viewConfigurationApp_.addCrow();
});

export default class configurationC{
   
    addCrow(){
        let $this = this;
        let r = $('.addCrow').attr("table");
        console.log(r);
        var t = $(r).DataTable();
        var counter = 1;
       
        $('.addCrow').on('click', function(){ 
            t.row.add( [
                counter +'.1',
                counter +'.2',
                counter +'.3',
                counter +'.4',
                counter +'.5'
            ] ).draw();
     
            counter++;
        })
        $('.addCrow').click();
    }
}
```

Es mi primera vez juego con datatables... puede que sea obvia la respuesta a simple vista pero no la tengo.. jaja

Answer (score 1):

Sinceramente yo no manejo Node.js, pero te comparto **3 diferentes maneras** de poder agregar registros/filas adicionales a un **jQuery DataTable**, esperando que te ayuden a solucionar tu duda:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {

var data = [
    {
    "Program": "Program 1",
    "Deliverable": "Monthly Status Report (MSR)",
    "To": "example@example.com",
    "Date": "03/30/2002",
    "Approved": "Yes",
    "Notes": "Example Notes"
        },
    {
    "Program": "Program 1",
    "Deliverable": "Meeting Minutes",
    "To": "example@example.com",
    "Date": "03/30/2012",
    "Approved": "No",
    "Notes": "Example Notes"
        },
    {
    "Program": "Program 2",
    "Deliverable": "Monthly Status Report (MSR)",
    "To": "example@example.com",
    "Date": "03/30/2002",
    "Approved": "Yes",
    "Notes": "Example Notes"
        },
    {
    "Program": "Program 3",
    "Deliverable": "Monthly Status Report (MSR)",
    "To": "example@example.com",
    "Date": "03/30/2002",
    "Approved": "Yes",
    "Notes": "Example Notes"
        }
];

var newData = [
   {
      "Program": "Program 4",
      "Deliverable": "Monthly Status Report (MSR)",
      "To": "another_example@example.com",
      "Date": "04/30/2002",
      "Approved": "No",
      "Notes": "Example Notes 2"
   }
];

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: [
      {data:'Program', title: 'Program'},
      {data:'Deliverable', title: 'Deliverable'},
      {data:'To', title: 'To'},
      {data:'Date', title: 'Date'},
      {data:'Approved', title: 'Approved'},
      {data:'Notes', title: 'Notes'},
    ]
  });
  
   $("#btnAddHTML").click(function() {
  
       var nData = newData[0];
  
       var jRow = $("<tr>").append("<td>" + nData.Program + "</td><td>" + nData.Deliverable + "</td><td>" + nData.To + "</td><td>" + nData.Date + "</td><td>" + nData.Approved + "</td><td>" + nData.Notes + "</td>").append("</tr>");
       table.row.add(jRow).draw();
   });
   
   $("#btnAddObject").click(function() {
  
       table.row.add(newData[0]).draw();
   });
   
   $("#btnAddData").click(function() {
  
       table.row.add({
         "Program": "Program 4",
         "Deliverable": "Monthly Status Report (MSR)",
         "To": "another_example@example.com",
         "Date": "04/30/2002",
         "Approved": "No",
         "Notes": "Example Notes 2"
      }).draw();
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Program</th>
      <th>Deliverable</th>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Date Submitted</th>
      <th>Approved</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<br>
<button id="btnAddHTML" >ADD ROWS (HTML)</button>
<br><br>
<button id="btnAddObject" >ADD ROWS (Object)</button>
<br><br>
<button id="btnAddData" >ADD ROWS (Data)</button>
```